# Does darkvision granted by a magic item affect what a caster can see in a dark location using the Clairvoyance spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, vision-and-light

The description of the [*clairvoyance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clairvoyance) spell states:

> When you cast the spell, you choose seeing or hearing. You can use the chosen sense through the sensor as if you were in its space.

The wording "as if *you* were in its space" arguably leaves room for ambiguity.

If a creature with innate darkvision -- e.g., an elf -- uses the spell to see into a dark location, there is no question that the caster would benefit from that darkvision. If "you," the elf casting the spell, were physically present in the dark location, you undeniably would have the benefit of your darkvision.

The same logic might not apply, however, to a creature who has darkvision solely by dint of a magic item. If "you," a human caster wearing *goggles of night*, were physically present in the dark location, whether you would benefit from darkvision would depend on whether "you" means *just you* or *you and your equipment*.

The by-now-familiar wisdom that spells do only what they say they do (and anything more is left up to the DM) seems not to resolve this issue, because it is not clear what the spell is saying it does.

**How does darkvision granted by a magic item interact with *clairvoyance*?**

Comment: Down-voters, can you offer any feedback as to what you find unhelpful or objectionable about this question? I really thought the ambiguity was apparent and problematic. If it helps for some reason, I'm the one playing the human casting _clairvoyance_, and my agenda with the question was simply to establish that a player-friendly reading (as supplied in the one answer submitted so far) is justified.

Comment: I was not one of the downvoters, but I think that there is not any ambiguity in the question: the sentence "as if you were in its space" is quite clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The word "you" would include equipment

The description might seem a bit vague, but 5E tends to treat "you" as being your character and whatever you are carrying.

As evidence, consider the [*time stop*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Time%20Stop#content) spell:

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row, during which you can use actions and move as normal.
>
> This spell ends if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that you create during this period, affects a creature other than you or an object being worn or carried by someone other than you. In addition, the spell ends if you move to a place more than 1,000 feet from the location where you cast it.

Nowhere in there does it mention your equipment. If you assume that "you" only means your physical body, then you are stuck in place as your clothes would be stuck in place. You'd not be able to move any potions you have to drink them, etc.

Comment: Also worth noting that the goggles of night say that "you have darkvision" while wearing them. Contrast with a gem of true seeing, which only works when you are looking through it.